# Notation for two functions

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Can someone please tell me how the following notation is named?
$A(x)\asymp B(x)$ (where $A$ and $B$ are two real functions)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$A \asymp B \iff \exists\, c,d>0 : c|B| \leq |A| \leq d|B|$.

Comment: yes but i need to introduce it in my article and i don't how to formulate a statement to do so. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks

Comment: "*i don't how to formulate a statement to do so*" --- Two possible verbal descriptions: (1) Their ratio is bounded away from $0$ and infinity. (2) Their relative error does not become infinite.